# Best way to place multiple icons side by side using autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

New to iOS development here - I want to place multiple icons side by side within a view

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |

Based on what I've read, the most flexible way to add constraints would be -

A - Leading, top and bottom constraints of 0 to it's superview + width constraint
B - top and bottom alignment with A, leading edge constraint of 0 with A + width constraint
C - top and bottom alignment with A, leading edge constraint of 0 with B + width constraint
D - top and bottom alignment with A, leading edge constraint of 0 with C + width constraint
E - and so on ....
.
.

This way, if A moves to the right or changes it's vertical alignment, everything else adjusts automatically(I think)

Is this the best way to achieve the above layout?

Answer (score 1):

For your current problem , I recommend using `UIStackView` ( Horizontal ) with `distribution` set to `fillEqually` , and if items exceed screen width , embed it inside a `UIScrollview` , or use a `UICollectionView` instead